# Memory wont get cleared from background thread in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, dispatch-queue

I have an app that is constantly reading data from my server and updating the data in the UI. It pulls quite a bit of data, builds some data structures, and then passes the information to the UI. The code below shows how I am collecting the data:

```
class Server {
    private var units: [Unit] = []

    ...

    init {
        // I pull data from a firebase realtime database here using the observe method
        // which triggers the callback everytime the data changes
        // 'data' is a big dictionary of dictionarys  which will be sorted into objects
        FirebaseDatabaseHandler.getServerInfo(serverAddress: address, callback: { data in

            // Because its a lot of data sorting it is hefty so I do this on a background thread
            // 'updateQueue' is a single static DispatchQueue that I create in AppDelegate for now
            AppDelegate.updateQueue.async {

                // here I create an array of data objects using the JSON I pulled from firebase
                // then I set the "units" variable of this object and call my update callback
                // which triggers a UI update on the main thread
                if let unitData = (data?["units"] as? [String:Any]) {
                    var unitsArray = [Unit]()
            
                    for key in unitData.keys {
                        unitsArray.append(Unit(address: key.base64Decode, data: unitData[key] as! [String:Any]))
                    }
            
                    self.units = unitsArray
                    self.updateCallback()
                }
            } 
       })
   }
   
   ...
```

The above code works fine, however the memory is constantly building and not being properly freed, after running for ~10-20 minutes the app builds up to 2GB of memory and crashes from running out of memory.

If I get rid of the `AppDelegate.updateQueue.async { }` and just let this code run on the main thread, the memory DOES get cleared and there are no crashes, the memory stays around 50-200mb, however if I do this the UI is essentially permanently frozen due to how much processing is happening on the main thread

Ive tried using the debugger to watch the size of my `units` array and my `Server` object, but neither grow in size no matter how long the app is running.

Is there anything I can do to debug this, or any reason why the memory wont get cleared when I run it from a background thread?

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments to debug the memory behavior of your application?  (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/)

Comment: I try creating your problem with a sample project, running on Global background thread, still get de allocate, can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @AchmadJP I will see if i can come up with an easy way to reproduce... maybe ill find the issue in doing so anyway :P thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Add [weak self]:

```
FirebaseDatabaseHandler.getServerInfo(serverAddress: address, callback: {[weak self] data in

    AppDelegate.updateQueue.async { [weak self] in
```

Note that you will need to make some more adjustments because self would become optional.

Comment: Just tried this, still seem to be having the same issue - will attempt to create a simple way to reproduce it